# when saving an array of objects as a JSON, I need to use the following format in Sample.txt to not run into parsing errors:

Tags: javascript, json

when saving an array of objects as a JSON, you need to use the following format in Sample.txt to not run into parsing errors:

```
[{"result":"\"21 inches = 21 inches\"","count":1},{"result":"\"32 inches = 32 inches\"","count":2}]
```

I'm new to JSON and searching over this for since last 4 days. I tried different approaches of storing an array of objects but no success. My first and simplest try is like this:

```
function createData() {
    //original, single json object
        var dataToSave = {
            "result": '"' + toLength.innerText +'"',
            "count":  counter 
        };

     //save into an array:
     var dataArray = { [] };    //No idea how to go ahead.. 


        var savedData = JSON.stringify(dataToSave);    
        writeToFile(filename, savedData);  //filename is a text file. Inside file, I want to save each json object with , in between. So It can be parsed easily and correctly.
```

}

```
function readData(data) {
    var dataToRead = JSON.parse(data);

        var message = "Your Saved Conversions : ";

        message += dataToRead.result;

        document.getElementById("savedOutput1").innerText = message;
```

}

Comment: Simply push the JSON obj into an array. This will create a Array of objects

Answer (score 0):

To make an array from your object, you may do

```
var dataArray = [dataToSave];
```

To add other elements after that, you may use

```
dataArray.push(otherData);
```

When you read it, as data is an array, you can't simply use `data.result`. You must get access to the array's items using `data[0].result`, ... `data[i].result`...